# input datetime set string.format to model item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, string-formatting

I've an input of type datetime

```
   <input type="datetime" id="DATA_END_@id" value="@String.Format("dd/MM/yyyy",item.DATA_END_PREZZATURA.ToString())" />
```

I need to set the model item value in the datetime format dd/MM//yyyy

What is the right sintax?

Thank you!

In the end this was the solution

```
@{
                string value_d_s = "";
                DateTime? dateOrNull = item.DATA_END_PREZZATURA;
                if (dateOrNull != null)
                {
                    DateTime date_d_s = dateOrNull.Value;
                    value_d_s = date_d_s.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                }

             }

            <input type="datetime" id="DATA_END_@id" value="@value_d_s" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an overload of the [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method to format your date.

```
<input type="datetime" id="DATA_END_@id" value="@item.DATA_END_PREZZATURA.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" />
```

If `item.DATA_END_PREZZATURA` is a `string` instead of a `DateTime`, you will need to use `DateTime.TryParse()`:

```
@{
    DateTime test;
    DateTime.TryParse(item.DATA_END_PREZZATURA, out test);
}
<input type="datetime" id="DATA_END_@id" value="@test.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" />
```

Note you will need to handle the case when `TryParse` fails.

Comment: thanks! <input type="datetime" id="DATA_START_@id" value="@item.DATA_START_PREZZATURA.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" /> gives me the error No overload for method ToString takes 1 argument

Comment: What's the type of your `item.DATA_END_PREZZATURA`? I assumed it's a `DateTime`

Comment: it's Nullable<System.DateTime>

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. In your view model

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DATA_END_PREZZATURA { get; set; }
```

In the View

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DtTime, new { type = "date" })
```